# QGIS Vector Toolbar Has No Tools

Tags: qgis, vector, toolbar

I am trying to use the Table Manager to rename a field in an attribute table.  However, the Vector Toolbar in my install of QGIS 2.14.0-Essen 64-bit Windows shows a toolbar with no tools in it.  The toolbar handle is visible, but not tools are included in it.  See photo below.

[image: screenshot of empty vector toolbar]

Furthermore, when I go into the Customization menu to try and add options to appear in the Vector Toolbar, I see that there are no options to add.  All the other toolbars have a plus next to them that give you the option to add or remove tools.  The Vector Toolbar has no plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Vector Toolbar** mainly contains plugins which deal with vectors (both core to QGIS and external ones), all of which must be enabled from:

*Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins*

Note that not all "vector" plugins will be shown in the Vector Toolbar, there are some which appear in other toolbars such as the **Plugin Toolbar**.

Just as an example, here is what I currently have enabled in my Vector Toolbar:

[image: Vector Toolbar]

(*from left to right*):

- Coordinate Capture
- Dxf2Shp Converter
- Spatial Query
- TopologyChecker
- GroupStats
- Statist
- Table manager